# Can I reverse the filechannel with certain bytes overpassed

Tags: java, filechannel

In my programming, I do not know how many bytes I need to read for a certain object util I processed it. But I know at most it is 1024 bytes.

After processing the object, how can I put the remaining bytes back to the file i.e., revserse  the fc by the number of remaning number of bytes.

I mean could I let the filechannel go back by a certain number of bytes, say 4 bytes from current position? –

Comment: By read an object do you mean to say your using a `ObjectInputStream`?

Comment: I used a filechannel and bytebuffer then use the bytebuffer to write into a bytearray

Comment: I mean could I rewind the filechannel by a certain number of bytes, say 4 bytes from current position?

Answer (score 0):

Using `FileChannel`s you can get and set the position very easily.

```
FileChannel channel = ...
// rewind 4 bytes
channel .position(channel .position()-4);
```